# MySQL Collation Issue

Tags: mysql, database, character-encoding

In my company, the tables in the database were poorly created. Each table has a different collation and charset.

This is very bad, sure, but it makes queries loose a lot of performance til the point the server crashes (and it isn't even a great database...).

I would like to know if there are any good MySQL tools, commands or procedures for converting table collation and charset.

Just executing the alter table and executing convert is braking special characters. Is it normal or I am doing something wrong?

**EDIT:**
As exemple: I have a table finance with uft8 collation and a table expense with latin swedish. Each table has between 1000 and 5000 rows. The following query takes about 15 second to execute:

```
select ex.* from expense ex
   inner join finance fin on fin.ex_id = ex.id
```

Executing much complexer queries with bigger tables runs much faster when they have the same collation.

**EDIT 2:**
Another error in the database: row ids are all varchar(15), not int.

Comment: Even if every single column had a different charset, it should not degrade performance too badly and it should not screw up special chars if everything else is handled properly. You should provide more details on what exactly is happening.

Comment: unless those id fields are text, the charset shouldn't affect performance at all on the join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recommend to use a "tool" to fix this.

**BEFORE YOU DO ANYTHING DUMP YOUR DB TO HAVE A BACKUP IN CASE YOU MESS IT UP ;)**

You can streamline your character sets and collation two ways

**Method 1: Move your data**

- Create a completely new database with correct character sets and collations configured in all tables
- Fill your new tables with INSERT SELECT statements
  e.g.

  INSERT INTO `newdatabase`.`table` SELECT * FROM `olddatabase`.`table`

MySQL will automatically convert your data into the correct character set

**Method 2: Alter your tables**

If you change the character set of a existing table, all existing contents will be converted as well

e.g.

old table

```
CREATE TABLE `myWrongCharsetTable` (
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_german1_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_german1_ci;
```

put some data in for demo

```
INSERT INTO `myWrongCharsetTable` (`name`) VALUES ( 'I am a latino string' );
INSERT INTO `myWrongCharsetTable` (`name`) VALUES ( 'Mein Name ist Müller' );
INSERT INTO `myWrongCharsetTable` (`name`) VALUES ( 'Mein Name ist Möller' );

SELECT * FROM myWrongCharsetTable INTO outfile '/tmp/mylatinotable.csv';
```

On a UTF-8 console I do this

```
# cat /tmp/mylatinotable.csv
I am a latino string
Mein Name ist M▒ller
Mein Name ist M▒ller
```

right, strange charset.. this is latin 1 displayed on a utf-8 console

```
# cat /tmp/mylatinotable.csv | iconv -f latin1 -t utf-8
I am a latino string
Mein Name ist Müller
Mein Name ist Möller
```

Yep, all good

**So how do I fix this now??**

```
ALTER TABLE myWrongCharsetTable
    MODIFY name varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
    DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

That's it :)

Writing the outfile again

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM myWrongCharsetTable INTO outfile '/tmp/latinoutf8.csv';
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> exit
Bye
dbmaster-001 ~ # cat /tmp/latinoutf8.csv

I am a latino string
Mein Name ist Müller
Mein Name ist Möller
```

Worked, all fine and we're happy

EDIT:

There's actually another method

**Method 3: Dump, modify and reload your data**

If you're good with sed and awk you can automate this, or edit the file manually

```
# dump the structure, possibly routines and triggers
mysqldump -h yourhost -p -u youruser --no-data --triggers --skip-comments --routines yourdatabase > database_structure_routines.sql

# dump the data
mysqldump -h yourhost -p -u youruser --no-create-info --skip-triggers --skip-routines yourdatabase > database_data.sql
```

Now open the `database_structure_routines.sql` in an editor of your choice and modify the tables to your needs

I recommend to drop all the comments like /*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */ in your dumpfile because this could overwrite table defaults

When you're done, create a new database and structure

```
mysql > CREATE DATABASE `newDatabase` DEFAULT CHARSET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
mysql > use `newDatabase`
mysql > ./database_structure_routines.sql;
```

Don't forget to recheck your tables

```
mysql > SHOW CREATE TABLE `table`;
```

If that's all right you can reimport your data, charset conversion again will be done automatically

```
mysql -h yourhost -p -u youruser newDatabase < database_data.sql
```

Hope this helps

Comment: added a 3rd method which would probably even be the simplest way for you but also has a few ways to mess it up :) Either way, create a backup first! ;)

Comment: I have executed so many tests that backpups are not a problem. The third method is the same as @ray 's, and as I told him, that will be the last resort. But thanks, stil.

Answer (score 2):

I know the fun of inheriting legacy schemas created by folks who think 'collation' is some form of illness.

The best option is to export the table with it's data to a SQL dump file using good ole' mysqldump.  Then modify the create statements manually in the dump file to set the character set and collation. I'm a big fan of 'utf8'.  If the dump file is huge, use command line stuff like `sed` to efficiently edit the file without having to open it in an editor.

Then drop the existing table re-import the modified dump.

Any other way you do this in my experience can be a roll of the dice.

This might be a good time to convert them all to the same storage engine as well or upgrade your MySQL server to 5.5.

Comment: I was afraid of having to resort to such solution. There are a lot of tables in the database... Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @LeandroBarreto yup and the big ones are really going to suck.  Congrats on catching the hot potato.

Comment: The longer you put off fixing your data, the worse it will be before you are finally forced to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using CONVERT or CAST to change the charset - create a new column and use CAST to fill the new column with new corrected charset.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, for some strange reason the alter table is breaking the special characters

Comment: Sorry, read it too fast.  I edited my answer with another idea.